# ie receives same ajax response

Tags: jquery

I have a ajax search that filters as you type. It works fine in chrome and firefox. However, no matter what data you send, IE always returns the same response. Why is that? Below is the code:

```
var cardSearch = $('<div>').addClass('card_search').appendTo($('body')).hide().css({'position': 'absolute', 'width': '350px', 'height': '300px', 'background': '#D5D5D5', 'padding': '10px'}).append(
    $('<div>').css({'background': 'whiteSmoke', 'padding': '5px', 'height': '290px', 'position': 'relative'}).append(
        $('<input>').css('width', '250px').bind('keyup', function(e){
            $.post('http://api.redemptionconnect.com/cards/find/?a=' + Math.random(), {data: {title: $(this).val(), limit: 10, page: 1}}, function(r){
                $('ul', cardSearch).empty();
                for( var i = 0; i < r.data[0].length; i++ )
                    $('ul', cardSearch).append(
                        $('<li>').append(
                            $('<a>').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)').html(r.data[0][i].Card.title + ' (' + r.data[0][i].CardSet.abbreviation + ')').attr('card_id', r.data[0][i].Card.id).mouseover(function(){showCardTooltip(this);})
                        ).css({'padding': '5px', 'border-bottom': '1px solid #ccc'})
                    );
            }, 'json'); 
        }),
        $('<button>').html('Search').css({'width': '70px', 'margin-left': '10px'}),
        $('<hr>').css('margin-bottom', 0),
        $('<ul>').css({
            'list-style-type': 'none',
            'margin': 0,
            'padding': 0,
            'width': '100%'
        })
    )
);
```

In chrome and firefox, the output is correct. In IE, the output is always the same, no matter what you type. I'm not sure what else to include. You can see it working at http://redforum.blackfireweb.com and click the "Search Cards" menu button.

Comment: What is the response?  What does the fiddler traffic look like?

Comment: I bet that `Math.random()` is the cause of all this. Try give it other values each time without it.

Comment: tried running it though here: http://www.jshint.com/ ?

Comment: @gdoron I wonder that as well. LordZardeck - Have you tried using $.ajax instead of $.post and specifying no cache? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for details.

Comment: tried in IE7 worked fine

Comment: instead of Math.random() use new Date().getTime() which is guaranteed to give you a new number each time

Comment: @asawyer I'm going to try that now

Comment: @LordZardeck. If that works, no reason for `timestamp` not working...

Answer (score 4):

IE can be quite heavy-handed when it comes to AJAX request caching. If you set cache: false in jQuery's .ajax object it will append its own cache-busting query string to the url:

```
$.ajax({ cache: false })
```

Add this above your $.post() and drop your own one, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Another option is to use `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` at the top of your script, which will apply to **all** AJAX calls, rather than just that specific one.

Comment: It's just a verbose use of timestamp... Read my answer.

Comment: $.ajax({ cache: false })- this will not affect another ajax call like $.post, is not a global method

Comment: Who knew!? Bloody IE!

Answer (score 1):

Try your code with `timestamp-ticks` instead of `random`:

```
$.post('http://api.redemptionconnect.com/cards/find/?a=' + new Date().getTime(),
```

You can make it even shorter with replacing `new Date().getTime()` with `+new Date`

```
$.post('http://api.redemptionconnect.com/cards/find/?a=' + (+new Date)...
```

---

The suggestion: `$.ajax({ cache: false })` equals to mine but verbose, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of it:

`cacheBoolean`:

> Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp' If set to
>   false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
>   **Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.**